# can two mysql version can share same port number?

Tags: mysql5, port-number

Hi 
I have mysql 5.0 and going to install mysql 5.5 
Can i use the same port 3306 for the both versions of mysql?
Will it create any problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two services cannot listen on the same IP address and Port concurrently.

You have to either

1. Change the port number of one of the instances.
2. Run one instance on a second network interface (i.e. a different IP address).
3. Do not run them concurrently.

This is not due to any Mysql version restrictions. Its just a port cannot be taken by more than one application to listen on, on the same network address.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, on different ip's.

Comment: on different ip's? i didnt get you. I have mysql installe on my local machine.

Comment: your server may have serveral ip's defined, even though just one network-card.

Comment: What about sockets? If mysql accessed from same HW i guess creating two diffent sockets (my.cnf) would be enough, and with better performance as well, or am I wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Two running servers cannot share the same port on the same computer.

But if you only ever start **exactly** one of the servers then it shouldn't be a problem.